# LinkedList in c# xamarin

Tags: c#, java, linked-list

I have a linked list which contains views. I want to assign the last view element in the list to another view variable.

This is what  I did :-

```
private readonly LinkedList<View> bufferedViews = new LinkedList<View>();
View myView = bufferedViews.RemoveLast ();
```

also  this:-

```
if (bufferIndex + 1 > sideBufferSize)
{
    releaseView(bufferedViews.RemoveFirst());
}
```

But I get an error saying :-

```
Cannot convert from void to Android.Views.View
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Xamarin issue. Your code is just broken. Both [`RemoveFirst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`RemoveLast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132182%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are `void` methods - they don't *return* the first/last elements, they just remove them.

You'll need to use the `First` and `Last` properties, then remove the first and last values afterwards - assuming you actually *want* to remove the value. (It's not clear from the code whether you really do.)

You could always write extension methods to do what you want though:

```
public static T FetchAndRemoveFirst<T>(this LinkedList<T> list)
{
    T first = list.First.Value;
    list.RemoveFirst();
    return first;
}

public static T FetchAndRemoveLast<T>(this LinkedList<T> list)
{
    T last = list.Last.Value;
    list.RemoveLast();
    return last;
}
```